# Can't connect to MYSQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize if this is a simple question but I'm really really new at coding. I've been trying to figure this out through my own research but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm having a problem connecting to MYSQL even though I can connect through my phpAdmin using the same data. Any idea what's going on?

I'm not sure what info you'll need to help me solve this so I included the files that I used to build my code. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

the error I get says **Sorry, could not connect to database**

*This code appears in header.php file*

```
$SERVER = 'localhost';
$USER = 'useradmin';
$PASS = 'password';
$DATABASE = 'mydatabase';


if (!($mylink = mysql_connect( $SERVER, $USER, $PASS))){
    echo  "<h3>Sorry, could not connect to database.</h3><br/>
    Please contact your system's admin for more help\n";
    exit;
}

mysql_select_db( $DATABASE )
```

*this code appears in my index.php file*

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('header.php');
include_once('function.php');

$_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo "<b>". $_SESSION['message']. "</b>";
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
?>

<form method='post' action='add.php'>
<p>Your Status:</p>
<textarea name='body' rows='5' cols='40' wrap=VIRTUAL></textarea>
<p><input type='submit' value='submit'/></p>
</form>

<?php
$posts = show_posts($_SESSION['userid']);

if (count($posts)) {
?>

<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='500'>

<?php
foreach ($posts as $key => $list) {
    echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
    echo "<td>".$list['userid'];
    echo "<td>".$list['body'] ."<br/>\n";
    echo "<small>".$list['stamp'] ."</small></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}else{
?>
<p><b>You haven't posted anything yet!</b></p>
<?php
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

*here's my function.php file*

```
function add_post($userid, $body) {
    $sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, stamp)
                    values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body)."', now())";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

function show_posts($userid) {
    $posts = array();

    $sql = "select body, stamp from posts
        where user_id ='$userid' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $posts[] = array(       'stamp' => $data->stamp,
                                                'userid => $userid
                                                'body' => $data->body
                            );
    }
    return $posts;

}
```

Comment: You can temporarily add [`mysql_error()`](http://jp2.php.net/mysql_error) to what you're printing in case of error in `header.php` to pinpoint why the connection is not being made.

Comment: Which file do you navigate to when this message is displayed? index.php?

Comment: does your mysql service is running?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: In the `if` statement in `header.php` just before `exit;` , add `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` then see what error it displays when your run it . Also try examples from this page : [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your MySQL to MySQLi.

**Header.php**:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","useradmin","password","mydatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

**function.php**:

```
function add_post($userid, $body) {

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts (user_id, body, stamp)
VALUES ('$userid', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($body)."', now())");

function show_posts($userid) {
$posts = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT body, stamp FROM posts WHERE user_id='$userid' ORDER BY stamp DESC");

while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$posts[] = array(       'stamp' => $data->stamp,
                                                'userid' => $userid
                                                'body' => $data->body);
}

return $posts;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not close a brace `}` for your first function, plus a missing quote and comma.

`'userid => $userid` should read as `'userid' => $userid,`

Also a missing closing semi-colon in `mysql_select_db( $DATABASE )` change to `mysql_select_db($DATABASE);`

(function.php)

```
function add_post($userid, $body) {
    $sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, stamp)
                    values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body)."', now())";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

} // <- missing closing brace

function show_posts($userid) {
    $posts = array();

    $sql = "select body, stamp from posts
        where user_id ='$userid' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $posts[] = array('stamp' => $data->stamp,
    'userid' => $userid,
    'body' => $data->body
                            );
    }
    return $posts;

}
```

---

(header.php)

```
$SERVER = 'localhost';
$USER = 'useradmin';
$PASS = 'password';
$DATABASE = 'mydatabase';

if (!($mylink = mysql_connect($SERVER, $USER, $PASS))){
    echo  "<h3>Sorry, could not connect to database.</h3><br/>
    Please contact your system's admin for more help\n";
    exit;
}

mysql_select_db($DATABASE);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `msqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect`.