# Can't seem to figure out this php error

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure out this PHP error for almost a day. Sigh. I'm really new to coding but I thought I had this figured out. When I run this code, I get an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'body' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /Users/baronjon/Sites/squaredb/functions.php on **line 20**

and here is the code:

```
<?php

function add_post($userid, $body) {
    $sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, stamp)
                    values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body)."', now())";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

}
function show_posts($userid) {
    $posts = array();

    $sql = "select body, stamp from posts
        where user_id ='$userid' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $posts[] = array(       'stamp' => $data->stamp,
                                                'userid => $userid          
                                                'body' => $data->body   //**This is line 20.** 
                            );
    }
    return $posts;

}

?>
```

Being new to php (and coding in general) I realize that this could be really simple. But I don't see the parenthesis that it's telling me to look for.

I looked in the php manual to make sure I had the syntax correct and it seem pretty straightforward.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Even stackoverflow code highlight points you to it

Comment: Look at your array declaration: what's different about how you're defining the `'stamp'` entry and the entry following it.....

Comment: You should definitely use a syntax highlighting editor like `gedit`, `vi`, `emacs`,...

Comment: damit dont make me scroll to the right either

Comment: It's because you accepted [`the wrong answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22601725/) in [`your other question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22600908/) and making the same mistake, *again.*

Comment: @Fred -ii-: how dare you to even assume the OP is going to make even a keystroke to solve their issue. That's what SO is for: to fix dummy syntax errors

Comment: this is not Syntax Organiser ?

Comment: @OP: `Line 20` doesn't necessarily mean that the error is only on THAT line.

Comment: I want to be a productive member. Can someone tell me why my question was voted down? I put in a lot of work researching before I asked the question. The solution ended up being simple, but sometimes it's hard to see a problem when you've been working on it for so long. Also, I'm extremely new to coding. I've just finished code academy and lynda.com and i'm merely writing this code to practice and get better.If I'm asking my question on the wrong site, let me know so I don't waste anyone's time. I'll be happy to look elsewhere for help if this isn't the right place for this kind of question?

Comment: @user3404084 Don't worry about them :). Seriously though, use a text editor with syntax highlighting. It makes it much easier to visualize code and see where you went wrong. I recommend Sublime Text. It has a "free" trial that never expires.

Comment: [`Read this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623388/cant-seem-to-figure-out-this-php-error#comment34451533_22623388) @user3404084

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `$posts` array you are missing a trailing `'` quote, and a comma.

`$posts` array should look like:

```
$posts[] = array(      
  'stamp' => $data->stamp,
  'userid' => $userid,       
  'body' => $data->body  //**This is line 20.** 

);
```

Many times in PHP, when it says line 20, you should be looking at line 19.

As a commenter above mentioned I would really recommend using a code editor with syntax highlighting like vim, emacs, Sublime Text, Notepad++ or something similar. Saves my butt every day :).

Comment: that did it! can't believe I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: It seems clear the OP wanted an array of arrays, `$posts[] = array(...` was correct.

Comment: Ahh yes, missed that. My bad! Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an end quote on line 19 around `'userid => $userid` and a comma. It should be `'userid' => $userid,`.

Comment: OP was also missing a `,` after userid.

Comment: I know, forgot to add that in (saw it, just forgot in my orginal answer). As you can see i edited it :)